# How to "peek" Flask's flash messages?

Tags: python, flask

I want to check and see whether there are flashed messages in my Flask app. However, if I call `get_flashed_messages()`, then the items are drained from the message stack.

How can I "peek" or read the flashed messages without consuming them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from flask import session
flashes = session.get("_flashes")
```

If you want them without the categories, like `get_flashed_messages()`'s default then:

```
flashes = [x[1] for x in session.get("_flashes")]
```

I referred to [flask/src/flask/helpers.py](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/main/src/flask/helpers.py) `get_flashed_messages()` and `flash()` functions for the usage above.